# Use of Geolocation in Parse's Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, geolocation, geocoding

I have a user class with two types of users - customers, and vendors. There is a column (GeoPoint) called vendorLocation in user table which has coordinates of the vendor's shop but is left blank (null) for the customers.

When a customer places an order, a new object is created in the Order Class in which I store the address location as a GeoPoint. I want to find the vendor closest to him. I tried to write a cloud code but kept facing the same error over and over.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("assignVendor", function(request, response){
  var orderObjectId = request.params.orderObjectId;
  var query= new Parse.Query("Order")
  query.equalTo("objectId", orderObjectId);
  query.first({
       success: function(order){
         //order is the newly created parse order object
         //console.log("Order object found"+ order.get("orderNumber"));
         var userGeoPoint=new Parse.GeoPoint();
         //This is the problematic line
         userGeoPoint = order.get("customerLocation");
         var Query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
         Query.exists("vendorLocation");
         Query.near("vendorLocation", userGeoPoint);
         console.log("Reached here");
         Query.find({
           success: function(results){
                var chemist= results[0];
                  response.success("found "+vendor.get("profileName"));
                    order.put("vendorLocation", chemist);
                      order.save(null, {
                          success: function(result) {response.success("Saved")},
                            error: function(error) {console.log("Failed at save")} });
           },
           error:function(error){console.log("Cant find a suitable vendor")}
         });

    }, error:function(error){console.log("cant find the ");}

  });
});
```

The error shown in cloud code console.

```
E2015-10-06T11:23:40.858Z]v13 Ran cloud function assignVendor for user 4otr3l7YwG with:
  Input: {"orderObjectId":"OS5siGRXYW"}
  Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at e.Query.find.success (main.js:25:53)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:27927)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:26859)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26278)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:26987)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26278)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:26987)
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:14:26278)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:26931)
    at e.s (Parse.js:14:26859)

I2015-10-06T11:23:40.924Z]Reached here
```

The android code

```
        HashMap atMap=new HashMap<>();
        atMap.put("orderObjectId", "OS5siGRXYW");
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("assignVendor", atMap, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void done(String value, ParseException e) {
                if (e!=null){Log.d("failed ", +e.getCode()+e.getMessage());} else {Log.d("s", value);}
            }
        });
```

Error showed in android code is exactly the same as console, so I havnt posted it again. Error number is '141'

Answer (score 0):

Here's some help tracking down the cause of your problem.

1. make absolutely sure that the order number is being passed correctly
   and that the order with the object Id you are passing exists.
2. you may run into problems when directly assigning nested callbacks
   to the `first()` function. It is better to use `then()` to string promises together.
3. it is better to use `get()` than to use `first()` when trying to
   find a single object, as you should get an `object not found` error
   if `get()` returns nothing, preventing the `cannot call method get`
   error.

Let's clean up your code and see if it helps:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("assignVendor", function(request, response){
    var fetchedOrder;
    var orderObjectId = request.params.orderObjectId;
    console.log("orderObjectId = " + orderObjectId);
    var orderQuery= new Parse.Query("Order")
    orderQuery.get(orderObjectId)
        .then(function(order){
             fetchedOrder = order;
             console.log("Order object found"+ fetchedOrder.get("orderNumber"));
             userGeoPoint = fetchedOrder.get("customerLocation");
             var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
             userQuery.near("vendorLocation", userGeoPoint);
             return userQuery.first();
         })
         .then(function(chemist){
             order.put("vendorLocation", chemist);
             return order.save();
         })
         .then(function(){
              response.success("Success!");
         }, function (error){
             console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
             response.error(error);
         });
});
```

Notes:

- You dont need to define a new `Parse.Geopoint` before getting
  `customerLocation`. You are just reassigning a variable there.
- You dont need to check if the `vendorLocation` exists before
  comparing it to the `userGeoPoint`. If it doesnt exist, it simply
  wont get returned when using `near`
- I would advise using response.success only at the end all your
  promise thread
- After userQuery.find(), I believe that order does not exist in that
  context so I've set it as a function variable.
- There is no need to use `results[0]`, simply use `first()`